# Converting a multi-index dataframe to an excel format with the headers on top and reduction in repeating rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

[image]

I have been trying to convert a multi-index pandas dataframe to the excel format (below) without success.  I have tried using a pivot (and group by) for the multi-indexing, but in each case cannot get the number series (price) to augment to a single row without splitting out the dataframe and doing it manually ... "first name" and "mail" could be many columns with repeating rows, each for the car, term and price.  Ideally, I need to see a row for each "client" with a series of prices under the index levels as headers.

```
arrays = [
    ["tesla", "tesla", "toyota", "toyota"],
    ["12", "24", "12", "24"],
    ]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=('Car', 'Term'))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,1), index=index)
df1['name']='joe'
df1['email']='joe@mail.com'

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,1), index=index)
df2['name']='john'
df2['email']='john@yahoo.com'

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])    
df3.columns = ['price', 'first name', 'mail']
```

```
# Output =>
                price first name            mail
Car    Term                                     
tesla  12    0.181242        joe    joe@mail.com
       24   -1.292235        joe    joe@mail.com
toyota 12   -1.446640        joe    joe@mail.com
       24    1.119652        joe    joe@mail.com
tesla  12   -0.101694       john  john@yahoo.com
       24   -0.980943       john  john@yahoo.com
toyota 12   -1.004959       john  john@yahoo.com
       24    1.737056       john  john@yahoo.com
```

```
# Desired => 
                                 tesla               toyota 
                                 term                 term  
first name     mail         12          24         12        24
joe       joe@mail.com   0.181242   -1.292235   -1.44664    1.119652
john     john@mail.com  -0.101694   -0.980943   -1.004959   1.737056
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: your question is how to get from `df3` (output) to `desired` (exportable to csv so as to look like the image below), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closer but not exactly like your desire since `Term` is one of MultiIndex names from columns,

```
df3.reset_index(inplace=True)
df4 = df3.pivot(index=['first name', 'mail'], columns=['Car','Term'], values='price')
df4.to_excel('test.xlsx', merge_cells=True)
```

[image]

---

You can check
`print(df4.columns)`

Output:

```
MultiIndex([( 'tesla', '12'),
            ( 'tesla', '24'),
            ('toyota', '12'),
            ('toyota', '24')],
           names=['Car', 'Term'])
```

As you might guess,
`print(df4.index)`

Output

```
MultiIndex([( 'joe',   'joe@mail.com'),
            ('john', 'john@yahoo.com')],
           names=['first name', 'mail'])
```

---

#### supplement

Removing columns' multi-index names

```
df4.columns.names = (None,None)
df4.to_excel('test.xlsx', merge_cells=True)
```

[image]

Comment: That's great - I couldn't get it to work with "pivot" so I used "pivot_table" instead, which did the trick... do you know if "Car" and "Term" can be avoided?

Comment: `df4.columns.names = (None,None)`